# Background Outside of Body

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to add a background color to this site:

http://kerryaltmantest.info

I want the color to be outside of the blue border on the body table. Is there an easy way to add a background to the main site so the only white background is the body?

Comment: it depends much on your HTML structure, try using some div as the main content which is centered, then use background color for that div while use another background color for the body.

Comment: Something like `body { background-color: blue; }` ?

Comment: The thing is, you would need to modify your html quite a lot. The table structure does not seem to match in dimensions anything that is actually displayed on the page. Using `<div>`s to structure the page would be simpler and also make it more easily styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code, which fixes almost all the major layout issues in your site -

```
body{
   background:green;//color you want to define outside border
}
#wrapper {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; //making background white inside box
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden; //This will hide the content going out of your box
  width: 950px;// I see your table width as 950, so changed this to 950
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a coding issue. Another question...Is there a way to make it so the header is bigger than the body so it stretches out the way it was?

Comment: Add this css to body -                                 
body {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/K1W98DF.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 grey;//grey can be changed to the color you want
}

Answer (score 0):

in stylesheet, use

```
body
{
background-color : red; //suppose red
}
```

and now use < div> to put all other information or the  blue border

Answer (score 0):

In the **stylesheet.css**...

```
body {
background-color: black;
/* OR */
background-color: #ffffff; /*Hex Value*/
/* OR */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /*RGB Value*/
/* OR */
background: url(http://tinyurl.com/oaq99oc) #fff no-repeat; 
/* OR */
background-image: url(http://tinyurl.com/oaq99oc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current way you have the HTML set up, no there is no easy way. Try making placing all the items you have there in some sort of centered div. I tried modifying the color of your wrapper div, body, and html, and since there is no page-content containing div it colors everything that is not the table whatever color you choose. Once you have the content that you want surrounded with a background color you will do some sort of

```
#page-container { background:red; }
```

or

```
body { background:red; }
```

depending on what specifically you want and that will strictly place the coloring outside the main page info.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna set stretch Background image or else you can use from this plugin : [Backstretch plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

or you can set background-color on Html element.